# invalid byte sequence error loadin page on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to run project on Rails but I get this error:

```
Encoding::InvalidByteSequenceError in Sessiones#iniciar_session

ActionView::Template::Error ("\xC2" followed by "\\" on UTF-8):
    1: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    2:
    3: <div class="login-header text-center">
    4:   <!-- <% image_tag "logo/logo-white.png", :class => "logo" %> -->
    5:   <% image_tag "logo/logos-bat/texto-blanco/logo.svg", :class => "logo" %>
    6:   <!-- <% image_tag "logo/logos-/texto-blanco/logo.svg", :class => "logo" %> -->
    7: </div>
  app/views/sessiones/iniciar_session.html.erb:4:in `app_views_sessiones_iniciar_session_html_erb__3221493018978497249_47443666135760'
```

I work with

- Ruby 2.3.1
- Rails 4.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

To the top of whichever file is throwing the error